# Change Android smooth scroll behaviour on click

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener, smooth-scrolling

I have a `ListView` and with a `Timer` I control the scroll movement of this list by calling `smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, offset, duration)`. The `ListView` has a listener for `OnItemClickListener`.

If an item is clicked while the smooth scroll is happening, the scroll stops but the `onItemClick` event is not triggered. In order to do so you need to click again on the item.

I want to know how to override this behaviour. I mean, **if I click on an item while the smooth scroll is happening**, apart from stopping the scroll, **I want to trigger `onItemClick` on the item clicked**.

I really don't know if there is an easy way to do this. I tried with a `GestureDetector` for the `OnTouchListener` of the list and I listen to the `onSingleTapConfirmed` in order to call `performClick` in there, but I don't know how to get the position of the item being press from the `MotionEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution by using the `GestureDetector`:

```
final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MyActivity.this, 
  new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener(){
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        int position = listView.pointToPosition((int)e.getX(), (int)e.getY());
        if(position != ListView.INVALID_POSITION){
            listView.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
            //onItemClick code goes here
            //or call listView.performItemClick
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
});

listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});

listView.setSelector(android.R.color.transparent);
```

In my case, I added what I was doing in `onItemClick` inside `onSingleTapConfirmed` and removed the `OnItemClickListener` from the list. That's why I also added the `playSoundEffect` function to simulate the click.

In the last line I disable highlight on `ListView` click since lines got highlighted only when the smooth scroll was not happening. By disabling it I get the same behaviour for every click.