# Android: RecyclerView setOnTouchListener makes scrolling bad

Tags: android

I would like to add this GestureListener to my recyclerview:

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

    public OnSwipeTouchListener (Context ctx){
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                    result = true;
                }
                else if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
                result = true;

            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

But if I add this touchlistener to  my recyclerview, the scrolling is bad. It doesn't scrolling smoothly further if the user scrolls and raise the finger. How can I add this OnTouchListener and keep the "smoothly scrolling"?

Answer (score -1):

The [onTouchListener's onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) is always called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. so try adding this inside your `onTouch()` method and you can also use a switch on `event.getAction()` and the cases would be `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` as your requirements.

```
 if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

        // Do what you want
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```

Comment: I don't know what do you mean with that. The problem is that if the user raise the finger, the list isn't scrolling further. So it's a sudden stop that looks bad.

Comment: Yah [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802969/change-android-smooth-scroll-behaviour-on-click) answer may help you for that... Have a look... any try mixing the solutions